# Can we upgrade SharePoint provider hosted app to .net6.0

Tags: .net-core

Can we upgrade SharePoint provider hosted app from .NetFramework to .net6.0

Tried with upgrade assistant PowerShell command
upgrade-assistant upgrade --target-tfm-support LTS

Comment: Seems you don't get an answer to any of your questions. Probably you should elaborate a little more about your problems and what you have tried. In this question you said, what you tried, but nothing about what your problem is. So if you ran the upgrade assistant, did it succeed or fail? Did the outcoming code compile or not? Did it fail at runtime? In any failure, what was the exact error message and what is the corresponding code block leading to the error?

Comment: The upgrade is succeeded but application is not working. It's not launching the app URL. Code complied and success on run time. Didn't get any error message.